# UserPrincipal.SetPassword throws UnauthorizedAccessException when on Azure websites

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I can successfully set a user password using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, using:

```
using (var up = new UserPrincipal(principalContext))
{
   up.SetPassword(password);
}
```

However, when I execute the same code from an Azure website, it throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException` saying `Access is denied.`. This is the stacktrace:

`at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.SetPassword(DirectoryEntry de, String newPassword)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.SetPassword(AuthenticablePrincipal p, String newPassword)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordInfo.SetPassword(String newPassword)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthenticablePrincipal.SetPassword(String newPassword)
   at Cdp.ServiceBus.Adapters.ActiveDirectoryAdapter.CreateUser(String username, String password) in C:\agent\_work\a1b9797a\CDP\src\Cdp.ServiceBus.Adapters\ActiveDirectoryAdapter.cs:line 46`

The Active Directory instance is running on an Azure VM. The website is hooked up to the same Virtual Network. When developing locally, I'm connected to the same Virtual Network using a VPN.

The principalContext is setup using `ContextType.Domain` and `ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing`. I'm also specifying the virtual network's IP address as the name (which is the host) of the context. The username and password of this context is an admin in the AD VM.

Looking at the security log of the AD VM, I can see that when developing locally, a log entry is created because the admin I'm logged in with is trying to reset the password. When on Azure, no such log entry is created. From this I think I can conclude that the call is never received. There's no other log entry providing me with info that it has and/or is failing to process it.

My best educated guess would be that Azure does not allow to execute the SetPassword API. That would explain the rather low-level `UnauthorizedAccessException`. What do you think?

EDIT:

The signature of `SDSUtils.SetPassword` is:

```
[SecurityCritical]
internal static void SetPassword(DirectoryEntry de, string newPassword)
```

Is Azure allowed to run code attributed with `SecurityCritical`?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with this for a bit and I think I figured it out. In order for it to work the underlying connection must be secure:

```
PrincipalContext _pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "FQDN", null, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate, _svsUser, _svsPwd);
UserPrincipal _up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, usernameToChange);
_up.SetPassword(newPassword);
_up.Save();
```

Note the `ConextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate` in the constructor call. Once I added this and configured SSL on my DC, it started working.